# x509Certificate2 returning null - ssl certificate

Tags: .net-core, azure-service-fabric

I have installed ssl certificate and but when I use certCollection.Find by Extension but it's returning null.

```
private X509Certificate2 GetCertificateFromStore()
    {

        X509Certificate2 x509Certificate2;

        var aspNetCoreEnvironment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
        if (string.Equals(aspNetCoreEnvironment, "Development", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            const string aspNetHttpsOid = "1.3.1.1.3.1.1.84.1.1";
            const string cnName = "CN=localhost";
            using (var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
            {
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
                var certCollection = store.Certificates;
                var currentCerts = certCollection.Find(X509FindType.FindByExtension, aspNetHttpsOid, true);
                currentCerts = currentCerts.Find(X509FindType.FindByIssuerDistinguishedName, cnName, true);
                x509Certificate2 = currentCerts.Count == 0 ? null : currentCerts[0];
            }
        }
    }
```

Note: I have created a self-signed development certificate with below commands.

```
PS C:\program files\microsoft sdks\service fabric\clustersetup\secure> .\CertSetup.ps1 -Install -CertSubjectName CN=mytestcert
```

after installing i can see certificate is created with added into Trusted root.

[image]

Am I making some mistake in creating self signed certificate. I am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

You have stored the certificate in `StoreLocation.CurrentUser` but you code is looking in `StoreLocation.LocalMachine`.

Also, don't forget to the add proper [ACL's](https://github.com/Azure/Service-Fabric-Troubleshooting-Guides/blob/master/Security/Set%20ACL%20for%20a%20SF%20certificate.md).